# Django ImportError: No module named 'collection'

Tags: python, django, forms

As stated in the title, I keep getting an error when trying to create a form. It's on the line that has:

```
from collection.forms import contact_form
```

An I'm getting the error:

```
 File "/home/mike/CINS465/465proj/project/firstapp/views.py", line 2, in <module>
    from collection.forms import contact_form
ImportError: No module named 'collection'
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? I'm new to django and this was pulled from a tutorial on creating a contact form. I thought collection was built-in to django

Edit:

from views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .models import *
from .forms import contact_form

# Create your views here.
def contact(request):
    form_class = contact_form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form_class,
    })
```

from urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'contact/$',views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

from contact.html

```
{% block title %}Contact - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Contact</h1>
<form role="form" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

from forms.py

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class contact_form(forms.Form):
    contact_name = forms.CharField(label='Contact Name', max_length=255)
    contact_email = forms.CharField(label='Contact Email',max_length=255)
    contact_message = forms.CharField(
        label='Contact Message',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
```

I didn't include code that was irrelevant (i.e. index page).

Comment: isn't it called `collections`?

Comment: `collection` is an app being created in that tutorial, not a part of Django

Comment: what is your directory structure look like? @Mike1982

Comment: hmm ok. I changed it to collections and get ImportError: cannot import name 'views'.

Comment: What part of the directory structure? Like where my views, urls, and forms live?

Comment: ah nvm, in my original code I had from .forms import *, which did what I needed it to do (in place of what they did in the tutorial). Thanks for responses

Comment: @Mike1982 Is better that you understand this error, so it does not happen again. As it is, it tells you that can't find the view `contact_form`, so maybe you mispelled the name of the method. Check your views.py inside the collection app.

Comment: thank you for your response. I checked everything made sure it's spelled correctly. However, my form is not displaying. Updating original post with full code.

Comment: ah ha got it. I just realized I forgot to add {% block content %} {% endblock %} in my base. So stupid, lol

Comment: Don't call you app `collections`. There's a module in the standard library with that name, and using the same module name is very likely to cause problems. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html

Comment: Have you manually renamed the folders or anything?
I could see from "/home/mike/CINS465/465proj/project/firstapp/views.py" that view is within a module called `firstapp`. I will assume, forms.py is also in the same module, right?

Comment: Also, try using absolute import, instead of relative import.

Comment: yeah i saw that. I just have to use .forms import contact_form, which I assume is referring to the same directory that views.py is in. I think the tutorial had forms.py in a collection folder, which it didn't show. Thanks, I got it all figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty file called `__init__.py` in the app directory to make it into a package. If you don't have that file, you cannot perform submodule imports.

```
touch /home/mike/CINS465/465proj/project/firstapp/collections/__init__.py
```

Comment: You can read an explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for

Comment: we don't need to add an `__init__.py` anymore with py3